# Question related to interpretation of Empirical CDF

Tags: interpretation, presentation, academia, text-summarization

Following is the results from my experiments. Pink and Green are my proposed algorithms. While Blue is the brute-force (BF) algorithm. While one thing is obvious that BF algorithms take a lot of time to give optimal results and hence my algorithms (being sub-optimal) are still considerable.

However, I want to study this graphs as one more aspect i.e. my algorithms give more stable output on the contrary brute-force algorithms gives varied outputs (eCDF between 3.75 to 8.2). How can I put this statement in the academically sound manner?

[image]

Comment: You cropped the image beyond where we can see what the axes are. Is the $x$-axis time in seconds?

Comment: x-axis is ergodic rate, and y-axis is Emprical CDF. Sorry but this was part of a subplot so had to crop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, it is easier to judge the positions and overlap of these empirical functions if you plot the empirical probability density function (PDF) rather than the cumulative density function (CDF).

You could then report a confidence interval for the observed average times and conclude that both the point estimate of the brute force algorithm lies higher and that its confidence interval is wider (this is what I presume you mean by *gives varied outputs*).

---

Alternatively, you could consider what kind of distribution would make sense for these data (running times) and fit said distribution to each of the groups. For example, if these are discrete waiting times in seconds, you might get a reasonable fit with a Poisson GLM. In $\textsf{R}$ you could do this as follows:

```
Model <- glm(time ~ algorithm, family = poisson(link = "log")) # Poisson GLM
coef(Model)    # point estimates
confint(Model) # confidence intervals
```

The intercept of the model will be the first algorithm (you can check this by `levels(algorithm)` and change it by `relevel(algorithm, "new reference group")`).